# KVM Virtualization Host Upgrade from RHEL 5 to RHEL 6

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have Linux KVM guests running on CentOS 5.5 hosts.  These guests usually run CentOS 5.5 also.  Now I will have a RHEL 6 cluster.  I need these guests to be moved to the RHEL 6 cluster.  I do not need to upgrade the guests' OS as customers like their computing environment to be intact.

I use an iSCSI raid for the guest's storage.  If I mapped the iSCSI target to the RHEL 6 cluster, would these guests work without change?  Or I need to do something to make them work?

Answer (score 1):

to simply move a guest between two standalone RHEL hosts you'd need to make sure you have the image and the xml for the guest copied, and to adjust the XML for the new network bridge (or create the same network config on the destination host)

as an alternative, you might want to use virt-v2v - it can automate the process, even though in your case it's hardly necessary